# Have Paypal Check Out Button redirect to Payment page with 'Pay with a debit or credit card' heading

Tags: paypal

Couldn't find a definitive answer for this online.

Right now, when clicking on a 'Check out with Paypal' standard payments button on my website, users get redirected to a login page with two options: 'Pay with my paypal account' or 'Don't have a Paypal Account' 
[image]

My question is how can I get the 'Don't have a paypal account?' text to instead say 'Pay with a debit or credit card' like I've seen in some screenshots (see below). 
[image]
I know that the login page displays differently depending on the users cookies, but I've tried with different cookie combinations and still can't get the 'Don't have a paypal account?' text to change.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Express Checkout, you may be looking for adding SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole to the initial SetExpressCheckout API request

But, from your screenshot, I think the bottom is accepting credit cards with a Guest Checkout / Account optional, as joining Paypal looks to be "(Optional)".  What do you get when you click to expand that section?

Keep in mind it will be automatically expanded for customers who don't have a PayPal account email stored in their browser cookies. (e.g. if this were a brand new computer or they'd just never used PayPal before).  To test this condition, use Chrome's incognito mode or Firefox private browsing mode and you will see the behavior with no PayPal email in cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It's simple just add your Paypal Payment form this hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">
```

Full Paypal Payment form for Developer

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourbusinesspaypalaccountemail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="YOUR TOTAL AMOUNT">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing"> <!-- This filed redirect to Billing Page -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="Your Success URL">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="Your Cancel Return URL">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have PayPal account optional turned on in your account.  This is found under your profile, and then under Website Payment Preferences.  Keep in mind that not all countries support this.  If your account is able to turn this on, once turned on you should see the option that you are referring to above on your checkout pages.

Comment: Where can I find an *updated* list of countries that have this option?

Comment: There is not a page that specifically lists what countries have this availability from the seller/merchant perspective or list what countries can pay with a credit card without having a PayPal account from the buyers perspective.  If there is a country in particular you are asking about, I can check to see what is available for the specific country.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on "PayPal Account Optional" in your merchant account to make the text change in 'Pay with a debit or credit card' and use SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole to make it the landing option

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is helpful but I have noticed that when you use mobile devices such mobile phones or iPads and you want to pay via PayPal, it will not give you an option to pay using your credit or debit card, instead the button with an option to "pay by debit or credit card" there is "create an account" button. On Windows laptops or pc I did not noticed this issue so I think it's something to do with the resolution on the device screen.

Answer (score -1):

You need [Website Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) in order to take credit cards (and a merchant account from your bank).

Comment: That's incorrect. I'm using a basic free business account and can take credit cards no problem. That may be country specific however.